# More efficient queries to get the last record of the previous months if exist or the first record of this month if not

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like ask suggestions about better ways to do query efficiently.
Let say I have a table called payment_info and customer_master.

`payment_info` table:

`created_date`(timestamp) | `customer_id` | `category` | `payment_amount` | `carryover_amount`

`customer_master` table:

`customer_id` | `carryover_amount`

From these tables, I need to query data based on a certain month and year (the interested month) as the following:

(1). If exists a record before the interested month, then find the `carryover_amount` of the last record from `payment_info` table

(2). If (1) is not satisfied, find the first record of the interested month, and calculate the `carryover_amount` based on the category from the `payment_info` table.

(3). If (1) and (2) are not satisfied, find the `carryover_amount` from the `customer_master` table

Let say: the interested month is `202007` (July 2020).

A select query that I could think of right now is as the following:

```
SELECT (CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM payment_info WHERE customer_id = a.customer_id AND to_char(created_date, 'YYYYMM') < '202007')
          THEN ( SELECT carryover_amount FROM payment_info WHERE customer_id = a.customer_id ORDER BY created_date DESC )
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM payment_info WHERE customer_id = a.customer_id AND to_char(created_date, 'YYYYMM') = '202007')
          THEN ( SELECT (CASE
                         WHEN category = 1 THEN carryover_amount - payment_amount
                         ELSE carryover_amount + payment_amount
                         END)
                   FROM payment_info WHERE customer_id = a.customer_id AND to_char(created_date, 'YYYYMM') = '202007'
          )
        ELSE (SELECT carryover_amount FROM customer_master WHERE customer_id = a.customer_id)
        END) AS carryover
  FROM payment_info a
```

This query works well for a small amount of data in the payment_info table. However, when the data is large enough, this query takes forever.
I know that the above query is not efficient, but I could not find a better way to solve the above problem. That is actually what I want to ask in this post. Is there any way to do a faster query regarding the above problem
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Note: I am using Postgres, and I am not allowed change the table structure.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by trying a lateral join:

```
select cm.*,
       coalesce(pi.carryover_amount, cm.carryover_amount)
from customer_master cm left join lateral
     (select pi.*
      from payment_info pi
      where pi.customer_id = cm.customer_id and
            pi.created_date < to_date('202007' || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') + interval '1 month'
      order by pi.created_date < to_date('202007' || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') desc,
               (case when pi.created_date < to_date('202007' || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') then pi.created_date end) desc,
               pi.created_date asc
      limit 1
     ) pi
     on true;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. With a bit modification this one can solve the problem also. Never use lateral join before, but this is definitely something must be mastered.

Answer (score 1):

When we are building a query specially for big dataset, Having a select statement in the select statement is bad practice. Please try to avoid that.

I am assuming created date has also time. You can change that as per your requirement. Below is skeleton of how I would do it. I hope it is what you are looking for:

```
With tmp AS(Select carrover_amount, customer_id from 
(Select carrover_amount, customer_id from payment_info 
where to_char(created_date, 'YYYYMM') < '202007' 
order by created_date desc) where row_num = 1)
    
,tmp2 AS(Select CASE WHEN category = 1 THEN carryover_amount - payment_amount
                ELSE carryover_amount + payment_amount END carrover_amount2, customer_id from (Select customer_id, carrover_amount, min(created_date) OVER() as first_dt, payment_amount, created_date from payment_info where to_char(created_date, 'YYYYMM') = '202007' 
order by created_date) where first_dt = created_date)
    
    
Select CASE WHEN t1.customer_id IS NOT NULL THEN t1.carrover_amount
            WHEN t2.customer_id IS NOT NULL THEN t2.carrover_amount2
            ELSE b.carryover_amount END carryover
from payment_info a LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp t1 ON a.customer_id = t1.customer_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN tmp2 t2 ON a.customer_id = t2.customer_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_tbl b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is very clever.
I learned new things from your answer. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem buddy.. :)